# Pending (Incomplete Transaction) - in-kind

Tags: wordpress

How do you get a pending in-kind transaction to complete?

Comment: Hi Cynthia. welcome. you may find you get better quality answers if you provide more info. eg was the above created at the backend or front end. provide screenshots etc. the more you help make it like we can 'look over your shoulder' the more helpful the answers are likely to be

Comment: and if adding info, do so by editing the original question, not via Comment or Answer